# How to map a virtual keyboard code to an arbitrary symbol on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry, keyboard-layout

I'm aware of [PowerToys' keyboard manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager), with which I can rebind a key from my keyboard to any other key, including (unused) virtual keyboard codes (e.g. <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to <kbd>VK 252</kbd>).

Now I would like to assign that code (<kbd>VK 252</kbd>) to something of my preference, say a specific symbol that is not on my keyboard layout (let's say `ə`). Is there a registry key or other way to do that without using something like AutoHotkey? Even better if there's a way to fulfill the first step too (i.e. rebind <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> to `ə` directly), since that would mean no software has to run in the background for the rebinding to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Negative - you need some background key software to intercept keys that
don't have [Scancodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode).

For keys that have scancodes, you may use a registry update to map one scancode to
another.
For a discussion of useful software see the article
[The Ultimate Guide To Keyboard Remapping](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-keyboard-remapping/),
which contains many details on key-mapping and also lists some software products
that facilitate the mapping: Sharp Keys, Map Keyboard and KeyTweak.

You may have a look at Microsoft's
[Keyboard Scan Code Specification](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc)
for more information, and you will find a table containing almost all scancodes
in Microsoft's
[Key Scan Codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa299374(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

For keys that do not have scancodes, you will need a background running product.
AutoHotKey might be the best here.